# To wrap back-end system clients or not in Spring

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I have an application with Spring, and I need to call many different types of back-end systems (legacy mainframe, ESB, RESTful...). If we take e.g. REST, I can implement a RESTful client with e.g. RestTemplate. I can A) have developers use RestTemplate client directly, to which they pass the service url and dataobject. Or I can B) wrap RestTemplate inside our own, back-end specific client and offer explicit methods that developers can use. The methods themselves would then ofcourse use RestTemplate and make the explicit back-end calls.

The good with A) is that changes in back-end systems to not need changes to client. Downside is that we don't hide the architecture. B) is more clear for developers and easier to "manage", but changes to back-end systems require us to update all applications that want to use the new back-end functionality. Even worse, a change in back-end system functionality may require all services to be updated.

Still, I am personally leaning towards option B), because it is provides such a nice separation of business logic and architecture services for developers.

Comment: B is better option and to able to make changes easily when back-end get changed you can make it configurable using property files or xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand how you came to the conclusion that clients don't need an update (option A) if they want to use new functionality or if the API breaks because of a change.
I think option B is better. But I would use the HTTP client [Feign](https://github.com/Netflix/feign) to create request templates and then publish the interfaces. This way you won't even have to wrap a RestTemplate and manually implement every request.

Comment: Thanks, I need to look into Feign also. Looks interesting.